# Can't understand how the community answer works in this typescripte Exercisme assignement

Tags: regex, typescript, set

I m learning typescript from scratch by making exercices on [exercism](https://exercism.io/tracks/typescript/exercises/pangram)

I successfully resolved the 5 th exercice of Pangram

My solution is as shown below

```
class Pangram {

     alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    constructor(private pangram:string) {
        this.pangram = pangram.toLowerCase().normalize()
    }

    isPangram():boolean{
        for( let leter of this.alphabet){
            if(this.pangram.indexOf(leter) < 0) return false 
        }
        return true;
    }
}

export default Pangram
```

To become better I m trying to look at others solution to learn from and this  one took my attention since I m not that good at regex (yet)

```
class Pangram {
    constructor(private text:string) {
    }

    isPangram():boolean {
        var set = new Set(this.text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''))
        return set.size == 26        
    }
}

export default Pangram
```

I m not getting this well since at first read I though this gonna replace all letters in the text with empty char so I thought that he will check the size equals to zero why, he is  checking to 26 how really this work, I don't know how to debug I have only a test to run to be sure that is working fine, and his solution is working really fine

Please what really is happening in the second solution

I m adding the used unit test set for this assignment for curious readers

```
import Pangram from './pangram'

describe('Pangram()', () => {
  it('empty sentence', () => {
    const pangram = new Pangram('')
    expect(pangram.isPangram()).toBe(false)
  })

  it('pangram with only lower case', () => {
    const pangram = new Pangram("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
    expect(pangram.isPangram()).toBe(true)
  })

  it("missing character 'x'", () => {
    const pangram = new Pangram("a quick movement of the enemy will jeopardize five gunboats")
    expect(pangram.isPangram()).toBe(false)
  })

  it("another missing character 'x'", () => {
    const pangram = new Pangram("the quick brown fish jumps over the lazy dog")
    expect(pangram.isPangram()).toBe(false)
  })

  it("pangram with underscores", () => {
    const pangram = new Pangram("the_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog")
    expect(pangram.isPangram()).toBe(true)
  })

  it("pangram with numbers", () => {
    const pangram = new Pangram("the 1 quick brown fox jumps over the 2 lazy dogs")
    expect(pangram.isPangram()).toBe(true)
  })

  it('missing letters replaced by numbers', () => {
    const pangram = new Pangram("7h3 qu1ck brown fox jumps ov3r 7h3 lazy dog")
    expect(pangram.isPangram()).toBe(false)
  })

  it('pangram with mixed case and punctuation', () => {
    const pangram = new Pangram("\"Five quacking Zephyrs jolt my wax bed.\"")
    expect(pangram.isPangram()).toBe(true)
  })

  it('pangram with non-ascii characters', () => {
    const pangram = new Pangram("Victor jagt zwölf Boxkämpfer quer über den großen Sylter Deich.")
    expect(pangram.isPangram()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd be baffled by that as well, I don't think that is in anyway checking whether or not a sentence has used every letter of the alphabet, `isPangram` must be returning false, surely

Comment: it well tested and works fine and it have so much stars in the exercism.io website

Comment: It removes all *non*-letters (the `[^`...`]` notation represents a [negated character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges)), puts them in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which keeps track of only *distinct* values.

Comment: Could've sworn `^` meant "at the start of"

Comment: @jcalz so my normalize equivalent was done using the `/[^A-Za-z]/g` If I got it right here we tell it to remove all non ascii chars, what about the set why the size is 26 ?

Comment: @zanderwar A caret means "at the start of" unless it is at the start of a square-bracketed character class in which case it does not mean that, but it means that "not"; [what's the problem?](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: It removes all non-*alphabetic* characters (other characters like `#` and `1` are still ASCII) so if a lowercase string has exactly 26 distinct alphabetic characters between `a` and `z`, and there are 26 letters in the alphabet, then it must have all the characters in the alphabet.

Comment: please @jcalz make your comment an answer this way I close this question, thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
var set = new Set(this.text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''))
```

The regular expression matches all non-alphabetic characters (or, more accurately, all characters not in the [ISO basic Latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet)).  So the string passed into the `Set` constructor will contain lowercase versions of all the alphabetic characters in the `text` string.

The [`Set` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Parameters) takes an iterable parameter and walks through it, adding only one of each of its distinct elements to the set.  A string is an iterable object whose elements are the characters in the string.  So `new Set("pangram")` will be a `Set` containing exactly the 6 elements `"p"`, `"a"`, `"n"`, `"g"`, `"r"`, and `"m"`.  Note that it has 6, not 7 elements.  The string `"pangram"` has two instances of the letter `"a"`, but a `Set` contains only unique/distinct elements.  Thus `(new Set("pangram")).size` is `6`.

There are exactly 26 distinct letters in the lowercase basic Latin alphabet.  If a string containing only lowercase letters is passed into the `Set` constructor, the `size` of the resulting `Set` can be no more than 26.  If it is exactly 26, that means that at least one of each of the 26 letters must have been present... meaning that the original string is a pangram.  If it is less than 26, then the original string must be missing at least one of the 26 letters of the alphabet, meaning it is not a pangram.

So, `str => new Set(str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'')).size === 26` is a concise way to write a function to classify whether its input string is or is not a pangram.  Conciseness has its merits, although it can be absurd [when taken to extremes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf).

Okay, hope that helped.  Good luck coding!

Comment: would you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434342/typescript-modulo-not-working-test-failed) please